# What temperature should I use to desolder a FPC connector by heating the back side of the PCB with a hot air gun?

Tags: soldering, hot-air

I am learning how to use a hot air gun on PCBs.

I saw some videos of FPC connectors being desoldered by heating the back side of the PCB with a hot air gun. I am assuming it is being done to prevent melting of the plastic of the connectors.

Is that an acceptable or even the preferred way of doing it? If so, at what temperature and airflow rate would one do that?

Comment: You don't have to care about the plastic if you are replacing the connector anyway. Also since these are often located at the card edge, you don't have to worry so much about nearby components. The main concern in my experience of fine pitch <0.5mm is not connected pads. Depending on PCB quality, there's a chance of these coming off along with the connector - which won't affect the function, but it looks fishy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of videos of repair processes by really skilled electronics technicians. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/@ststele) is one, and he frequently mentions the temperatures and flow rates he is using to repair iPhones and such like, but keep in mind the flow rate settings are going to be different for different hot air rigs. There are others, of course, and watching a variety of techs work won't hurt at all. Rework is a physical skill with some technical aspects and I think a video or in-person instruction is most helpful in learn it.

It's not just temperature, but how you play the airflow around and how much airflow there is.

Also practicing on something that doesn't matter before you  tackle something that is valuable to you. You need to be able to see what is going on, so lots of light and a microscope or magnifier is invaluable when dealing with smaller parts.

The best method depends what is around it, and what kind of solder was originally used and what all is around the part you are trying to remove. One method uses special very low melting point solder (eg. Chip Quik- some of which melt at less than 65°C) to dilute the original high melting point lead-free solder, which is then thoroughly removed using fresh desoldering braid and replaced with medium melting point solder such as leaded eutectic 63/37 to place the replacement connector. And with relatively copious quantities of liquid flux applied very locally at each step, then cleaned off with pure isopropanol and inspected before proceeding to the next step.

If the connector is broken, overheating it is not so much of an issue but you might want to shield adjacent parts from the air flow to prevent them from being blow off or overheated.